# Lazy load not working on images that are added by leaflet/mapbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, leaflet, mapbox

I have a website, http://atlantaartmap.com, and the main page is populated by http://atlantaartmap.com/art.js. There is a navigation bar at the bottom that appends a number of images from a geojson file while populating the rest of the map.

I am attempting to apply lazy loading to these images using http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload. The version of the website where I am testing this is at http://atlantaartmap.com/lazy.html, and it uses http://atlantaartmap.com/lazy_art.js to generate everything.

For some reason, I can't get these images to lazy load. Instead of applying it to the class "lazy," I am applying it to the "navthumb" class that I already have. I have tried a few other lazy load plugins (unveil being the main other one), and I have also tried stripping everything away from the basics and building it back up. Is this problem because of the way I have the lazy_art.js add the images to the navigation strip?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put your call to lazyload in your html page before you call your script

```
$(function() {
    $("img.navthumb").lazyload();
});
```

When this is called, your thumbnail are not yet created.

So you have to move this call to lazy_art.js

```
var oneArtPlease = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
    .loadURL('art.geojson')
    .addTo(map);

oneArtPlease.on('ready', function() { 
   $("img.navthumb").lazyload();
});
```

Ref: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/blob/v2.1.4/src/feature_layer.js#L54

Comment: Thanks for the response. The thumbnails are actually loaded later in the .js file (there is a comment towards the bottom). I tried moving the lazyload() to right where you said and also tot he very end (where it is now), and it still doesn't work.

I definitely appreciate the help, though. I've been learning js as needed during this project, and I think I might be over my head on this one problem.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked your problem. I have updated the answer with the correct code (hopefully)

Comment: Thanks! That is definitely an improvement, because the images actually load now, but I think the plugin might not be ideal for how I am trying to use it. The first image only loads once you go to the edge and back, and python's simplehttpserver log seems to indicate that they are all loading right from the start. The plugins page has some examples of horizontal lazy loads that I'll probably have to consult. In any case, this was extremely helpful for me because now I see why it wasn't working at all. Thanks again.

Comment: You are right. At the moment, lazyload plugin does not behave the way you would expect on your site. I'm doing something very similar here (http://www.franceimage.com/en/explore/?load=demo). Have a look at the source code. You may find what is wrong on your side. Good luck

Comment: Wow, that is remarkably similar. I'll definitely take a look at the code later. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Franceimage, is your project still around? I procrastinated on checking out your code, and now the site doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I have moved it here: http://www.franceimage.com/en/places-to-visit/explore/?load=demo